# Cannot Solve Java Deque Iteration Bugs

Tags: java, iterator, doubly-linked-list, deque, reverse-iterator

As I was testing, I discovered bugs within my code.

I am having trouble finding what is wrong with my `Deque` Iterator. It isn't iterating properly and I have no idea how to fix it. I have included screenshots of the failing tests and my completed code.

***A side note:*** My professor wants the iterator to **Dequeue elements** from the head when iterating forward OR reverse iterating so that is why the iterator is a bit more complicated to figure out.

**Failed Unit Tests screenshots:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZb7k.jpg

Thank you so much for the help!

Complete Source Code:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Deque<E> implements Iterable<E>
{
    private class DequeNode<E>
    {
        private DequeNode<E> _next;
        private DequeNode<E> _previous;
        private E _data;

        private DequeNode(E data)
        {
            _data = data;
        }
    }

    private DequeNode<E> _head;
    private DequeNode<E> _tail;
    private int _depth;
    private static final int EXCLUSIVE_INDEX_START = -1;


    public Deque()
    {
        _head = null;
        _tail = null;
        _depth = 0;
    }

    public boolean enqueue(E element) // This is INSERTION at the TAIL //TODO: DONE!!
    {
        DequeNode<E> newNode = new DequeNode<E>(element);

        if (isEmpty())
        {
            _head = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            _tail._next = newNode;
            newNode._previous = _tail;
        }
        _tail = newNode;
        _depth++;

        return true;
    }

    public void enqueueAll(Iterable<E> elements)
    {
        for (E eachElement : elements)
        {
            enqueue(eachElement);
        }
    }

    public boolean enqueueHead(E element) // This is insertion at the head //TODO: DONE!!
    {
        DequeNode<E> newNode = new DequeNode<E>(element);

        if (isEmpty())
        {
            _tail = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            _head._previous = newNode;
            newNode._next = _head;
        }
        _head = newNode;
        _depth++;

        return true;
    }

    public E head()
    {
        checkForStackUnderflow();
        return _head._data;
    }

    public E tail()
    {
        checkForStackUnderflow();
        return _tail._data;
    }

    public E dequeue() // This is removal at the head //TODO: DONE!!
    {
        checkForStackUnderflow();

        E removed = _head._data;

        if (_head._next == null)
        {
            _tail = null;
        }
        else
        {
            _head._next._previous = null;
        }
        _head = _head._next;
        _depth--;

        return removed;
    }

    public E dequeueTail() // This is removal at the tail //TODO: DONE!!
    {
        checkForStackUnderflow();

        E removed = _tail._data;

        if (_head._next == null)
        {
            _head = null;
        }
        else
        {
            _tail._previous._next = null;
        }
        _tail = _tail._previous;
        _depth--;

        return removed;
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        _head = _tail = null;
        _depth = 0;
    }

    public int depth()
    {
        return _depth;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return _depth == 0;
    }

    public Iterator<E> iterator()
    {
        return new DequeIterator(this, false);
    }

    public Iterator<E> reverseIterator()
    {
        return new DequeIterator(this, true);
    }

    private void checkForStackUnderflow()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
        {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Stack underflow captain!!!");
        }
    }

    private class DequeIterator implements Iterator<E>
    {
        // The instance variables used throughout the program.
        private int _index;
        private Deque<E> _theList;
        private DequeNode<E> _current;
        private boolean _iterateReverse;


        public DequeIterator(Deque<E> deque, boolean reverse)
        {
            _theList = deque;
            _iterateReverse = reverse;
            _index = 0;
            _current = _head;

            /* If the flag for reverse iteration is detected, then just start
            the index at the end and iterate from the tail.
             */
            if (reverse)
            {
                _index = _theList._depth - 1;
                _current = _theList._tail;
            }
        }

        public boolean hasNext()
        {
            boolean results;

            // If we are reverse iterating check if the index is > than -1.
            if (_iterateReverse)
            {
                results = _index > EXCLUSIVE_INDEX_START;
            }
            /* Getting here means that we are forward iterating so check if the
            index is less than size AKA if we have more elements to go through.
             */
            else
            {
                results = _index < _theList._depth;
            }
            return  results;
        }


        public E next()
        {
            // If we don't have more elements to iterate through then we throw.
            if (!hasNext())
            {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            // Update the current to descent if we are reverse iterating.
            if (_iterateReverse)
            {
                _current = _current._previous;
                _index--;
            }
            // If we get to here then just update the current value forward.
            else
            {
                _current = _current._next;
                _index++;
            }

            return dequeue();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the code updates the index value on each iteration and decreases the depth value on each dequeue operation of the iteration, there comes a use case where depth is lesser than the index value, hence returning an incorrect hasNext() value (which seems to be the root cause of all the failed test scenarios).

An easy way to implement hasNext() will be as follows :

return _theList._depth > 0;

This will work for the above use case since there is a dequeue() operation performed(which decreases the depth value) in each next() operation.